# Xpath search and next text

Tags: xpath

I want to search for a text in the product detail and get the text written in the next span, can you help me?

```
    "fiyat": '//*[@id="product-detail"]/[text()="Kredi Kartı/Banka Kartı İle Öde")]"))/following-sibling::span/span/text()',
```

Hi
I want to search for a text in the product detail and get the text written in the next span, can you help me?

I want to find the underlined text and get the text in the circle

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o9Eh.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath should be enough

```
//span[text()="Kredi Kartı/Banka Kartı İle Öde"]/../span[2]/span
```